# WebDriverException: chrome not reachable whenever I'm running tests on VM

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-hub

I have a windows VM running OS Windows Server 2012 R2.
Selenium Hub and Nodes are setup here.
Tests stop abruptly. This doesn't happen every time though, it happens intermittently.

```
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'M-AMS-DEVELOPER', ip: '108.61.189.113', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_241'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x0158C013+3194899]
    Ordinal0 [0x01476021+2056225]
    Ordinal0 [0x0130F4B0+586928]
    Ordinal0 [0x013057C5+546757]
    Ordinal0 [0x012916F0+71408]
    Ordinal0 [0x0128E229+57897]
    Ordinal0 [0x0128C64A+50762]
    Ordinal0 [0x012B1EE9+204521]
    Ordinal0 [0x012B1D0D+204045]
    Ordinal0 [0x012AFC1B+195611]
    Ordinal0 [0x01293B7F+80767]
    Ordinal0 [0x01294B4E+84814]
    Ordinal0 [0x01294AD9+84697]
    Ordinal0 [0x0148CE64+2149988]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x016FBE95+1400773]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x016FBB61+1399953]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x017031FA+1430314]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x016FC69F+1402831]
    Ordinal0 [0x01483D61+2112865]
    Ordinal0 [0x0148E5CB+2155979]
    Ordinal0 [0x0148E6F5+2156277]
    Ordinal0 [0x0149F26E+2224750]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x772E6A14+36]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77EBAB4F+143]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77EBAB1A+90]

Command duration or timeout: 61.41 seconds
```

Comment: can you try to update your driver version to the latest?

Comment: yes. I will. When I posted this question, tests were running

Comment: @SusanMustafa Which driver are you talking about ?

Comment: Selenium and chrome driver.  I don't know how you are testing...

Comment: Don't you have any other idea other than that. Everyone is looking to update the drivers. I have latest stable version of selenium 3.141.59. Chrome driver is also updated to match the version of chrome installed on the VM. And this has been a persistent issue. All tests keep crashing even when everything upto date. So any other solution is appreciated. Also you don't need to know how I'm testing. Focus on solving the problem

Comment: The reason I stated that you updated your driver, is because it specifically states (Driver info: driver.version: unknown) in your stacktrace :)

As you can see in a similar problem here https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues/350 It might give you ideas

Comment: I'm not sure why it is not showing the driver info there. But I assure that I was on latest driver always.

Comment: sorry to not be able to help further.  I wonder if there is an uncaught exception somewhere that causes this blow up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229192/discussion-between-rameshwar-and-susan-mustafa).